# How to stop jquery from removing child elements when inserting data via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parent-child

I am using this following code to insert data into an html structure but only either or of the following gets displayed. It seems to me that while I insert data via Ajax the child elements are getting removed by that. What to do so that I dont need to change the structure?

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").html('<div id="loader"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw fa-5x fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Waiting...</div>');
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "generate_list.php",
               dataType:"json",
               cache: false,
               success: function(result){
                     $('#list').html(result.heading);
                     $('#list ul').html(result.list);
               }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**PHP SNIPPET**

```
if($count > 0){
    echo json_encode(array('heading' => '<div id="found">Here is all!</div>', 'list' => $thelist));
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array('heading' => '<div id="empty_storage"><img src="icon.png"><br>Its lonely here!</div>', 'list' => $thelist));
}
```

Comment: what does `result` look like?

Comment: what do you mean? If I alert the data then its exactly the way I want.

Comment: Can you show what is in `result.list` and `result.heading` and what you want the final result to look like?

Comment: check this paste to get an idea http://pastebin.com/avq2amEd

Comment: about which  child elements you are talking ?

Comment: If I insert data in #list then <ul> gets removed and vice versa

Comment: Thanks a lot to all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax callback isn't what is removing your html (although it would if it were still there), your first line:

```
$("#list").html('<div id="loader"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw fa-5x fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Waiting...</div>');
```

Is actually removing your `<ul>` from your `#list` element... which is fine, if you add it back. Assuming `results.heading` is an `h1` tag (or similar) and `results.list` is a bunch of `li` elements, your ajax callback could look like this:

```
$('#list').html(result.heading);
$('#list').append($('<ul>').append(result.list));
```

---

Also: If you want your loader to show between each interval... you could do this (or something similar depending on how it looks - this would put the loader icon at the bottom of your list while the list is being updated.):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $list = $('#list');
    setInterval(function(){
        $list.append('<div id="loader"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw fa-5x fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Waiting...</div>');
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "generate_list.php",
               dataType:"json",
               cache: false,
               success: function(result){
                     $list.html(result.heading);
                     $list.append($('<ul>').append(result.list));
               }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Short and sweet. Works just the way I want.

Comment: @Ayan, I'm not sure if you'd want it or not, but I added an example of a way you could do it that would show the loading icon everytime it's loading new data. Also caching the `$list` jquery object so it doesn't have to be recreated each time you want to touch `$('#list')`

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip ☺

Answer (score 2):

Use .append() instead of .html() so that content will be appended instead of overwrite:

```
  $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "generate_list.php",
           dataType:"json",
           cache: false,
           success: function(result){
                 $('#list').html(result.heading); // use html here
                 $( "<ul></ul>" ).appendTo( "#list" ); // create ul element in #list
                 $('#list').find("ul").html(result.list); // add list into ul
           }
    });
```

Comment: `prepend` might be preferable to `append`

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var list = $('#list');
    list.append('<div id="loader"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw fa-5x fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i><br>Waiting...</div>');
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "generate_list.php",
               dataType:"json",
               cache: false,
               success: function(result){
                     list.children('div').not('.loader').remove();
                     $(result.heading).insertAfter('.loader');
                     list.find('ul').empty().append(result.list);
                     //if result.list is a array you need to use a loop to append each value to the list
                     //$.each(result.list,function(i,c){list.find('ul').append(v);})
               }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: using append will repeat the whole set of data again and again

Comment: you have duplicate data in your result?, can you provide a sample result json?

Comment: The loader and the heading works fine but the list is not shown.

Comment: is your list a array?

Comment: That's because it's trying to add the list to `ul` after the `ul` got removed with the line before `setInterval()`... the first line of the callback would also remove the `ul` if it were still there.

Comment: a better solution will be to buid the html with the javascript and to pass from the server only the content of the html, this saves time and bandwith

Comment: a even better solution is to use server-sent events or websokets to send the data just when is updated on the server

Comment: Thanx a ton for your help. It was really knowledgeable to know from.

Answer (score 1):

As posted above, you should use:

```
$('#list').append(result.heading);
```

Html(something) will replace everything inside the selected tag with the content you pass as a parameter (When passing a parameter its basicaly an `.innerHTML="something";`), while append just add it to the current content.

.`html(something)` to replace.
`.append(someting)` to add.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append the html instead of replacing the html:

```
$('#list').append(result.heading);
$('#list').find("ul").html(result.list);
```